# UI update with GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, opengl-es

I'm writing a simple UI activity, the intention of which is to create an offscreen OpenGL surface and have a GL test render into it in a background GL thread. The rendering should start at a click of the button and the TextView should display some environment information (OpenGL version, etc.) as well as the test progress (as it may take a while) and result. In the sample I'm providing I have a 5 second delay in the 'run' function of the Runnable, but in the actual app code I have a JNI call to a native library that has the GL rendering code.

I've verified that the problem I'm experiencing exists with the 5 second delay as well as the original JNI call. The problem is that while the test is running (a 5 second delay in this sample), UI seems to be frozen and does not update until the test is done. The text that I'm setting to my TextView only appears when the test is finished. I thought that "queueEvent(new TestRunnable());" starts the runnable in a separate GL thread so that UI thread can continue with no interruptions, but it does not seem to be the case, or something else is missing. Do you guys/gals have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The simplified layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startTestButton" android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/startTestButton" android:onClick="onStartTestClick"/>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logView" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <com.company.name.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The simplified activity class is defined as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private String m_LogText = null;
    private Button m_StartTestButton = null;
    private TextView m_TestLog = null;
    private MyView m_SurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        m_StartTestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startTestButton);
        m_SurfaceView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
        m_TestLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logView);

        // Check for OpenGL 2.0 support.
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo info = am.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();

        m_LogText = "Open GLES version detected: " + Integer.toHexString(info.reqGlEsVersion) + "\n";
        m_TestLog.setText(m_LogText);
    }

    public void onStartTestClick(View view)
    {
        //
        // This text here does not appear until the end of the test:
        //

        m_LogText += "\nStarting the test: default\n";
        m_LogText += "Test is running, please wait...\n";
        m_TestLog.setText(m_LogText);

        m_SurfaceView.StartTest();
    }
}
```

Simplified MyView class is defined as follows:

```
public class MyView extends GLSurfaceView
{
    private TestRenderer m_Renderer = null;

    private class TestRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
    {
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) { }
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) { }
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) { }

        class TestRunnable implements Runnable
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }

        public void StartTest()
        {
            queueEvent(new TestRunnable());
        }
    }

    public MyView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        m_Renderer = new TestRenderer();
        setRenderer(m_Renderer);
    }

    public void StartTest()
    {
        m_Renderer.StartTest();
    }
}
```